# Datatable recommandation for django

Tags: django, search, datatable, server-side, large-data

I want to load millions of data from Django with search bars on each column to search all the database quickly on server-side. However, there is no datatable example for django with server-side and column search bar.

I tried django-datatable-view and I can load the dataset with server-side. But I could not implement the column searchbar on the whole dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at Datatable's **Server-side processing** option, DataTables will perform an Ajax request for each datatable manipulation like  paging, searching ...

[Server-side processing](https://datatables.net/manual/server-side)

however you will have to implement datatable in a native way

Comment: Thanks for your quick comments. Yes, I have finished the paging, however, I couldn't add search bar on every column and the search is only for this page (What I want is the whole database). Could your solution help with this? I haven't tried, sorry. Thanks anyway !

Comment: as i said before Server-side processing perfom an ajax call to server side instead of just searching in the DOM, so yes with this option you can search in your database

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have finished it. :)

Answer (score 0):

It seem you queries are most search extensive in huge Data. I would recommended using Elastic Search